# HTML table appears different in Gmail compared to a browser

Tags: html, css

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" height="131" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="570" height="131">
                        <img title="header_agado_zg_lv.jpg" alt="header_agado_zg_lv.jpg" border="0" src="http://em.agadomarketing.com/admin/temp/user/2/header_agado_zg_lv.jpg" width="570" height="131">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <table width="130" height="131" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td><img title="header_agado_zg_ds1.jpg" alt="header_agado_zg_ds1.jpg" src="http://em.agadomarketing.com/admin/temp/user/2/header_agado_zg_ds1.jpg" width="130" height="19" border="0"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="height: 25px;">
                                <td style="height: 25px;"><a href="#"><img src="http://em.agadomarketing.com/admin/temp/user/2/header_agado_zg_ds2.jpg" width="130" height="25" border="0"></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><img title="header_agado_zg_ds3.jpg" alt="header_agado_zg_ds3.jpg" src="http://em.agadomarketing.com/admin/temp/user/2/header_agado_zg_ds3.jpg" width="130" height="12" border="0"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="#"><img src="http://em.agadomarketing.com/admin/temp/user/2/header_agado_zg_ds4.jpg" width="130" height="25" border="0"></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><img title="header_agado_zg_ds5.jpg" alt="header_agado_zg_ds5.jpg" src="http://em.agadomarketing.com/admin/temp/user/2/header_agado_zg_ds5.jpg" width="130" height="12" border="0"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="#"><img src="http://em.agadomarketing.com/admin/temp/user/2/header_agado_zg_ds6.jpg" width="130" height="25" border="0"></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><img title="header_agado_zg_ds7.jpg" alt="header_agado_zg_ds7.jpg" src="http://em.agadomarketing.com/admin/temp/user/2/header_agado_zg_ds7.jpg" width="130" height="13" border="0"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img title="header_agado_sp.jpg" alt="header_agado_sp.jpg" src="http://em.agadomarketing.com/admin/temp/user/2/header_agado_sp.jpg" width="700" height="152"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                            </table>!
```

Gmail:
[image]

Browser:

[image]

Why does the page appear different in Gmail to how it appears in a browser? How can I  solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have any CSS being applied to the elements that make your side links? (If so, post it!) E-mail clients, whether web-based or not, don't support everything that normal browsers do, and [support varies per client](http://i3.campaignmonitor.com/assets/files/css/campaign-monitor-guide-to-css-in-email-sep-2013V2.pdf). Some common things that Gmail doesn't support that you may be using is `<style>` tags (your styles have to all be inline) and CSS `position`.

Comment: do you use any reset.css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add Inline style to each image tag in email :

For example:

```
<img title="header_agado_zg_lv.jpg" alt="header_agado_zg_lv.jpg" border="0" src="http://em.agadomarketing.com/admin/temp/user/2/header_agado_zg_lv.jpg" width="570" height="131" style='border: none; display:block;' />
```

In short `style='border: none; display:block;'`